# setCredentials - can't resolve this method (Firebase Admin)

Tags: java

The errors I am facing is " setCredentials - can't resolve this method
initializeApp - can't resolve this method

```
  FileInputStream serviceAccount = new 
  FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
  FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://qrmoney-1aec0.firebaseio.com")
    .build();
  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

Note - I am importing everything.

Answer (score 0):

I took care of it Java Code Examples for com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions,There is no mistake in idea.Here is[pom.xml](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=firebase/firebase-admin-java/firebase-admin-java-master/src/test/java/com/google/firebase/database/integration/FirebaseDatabaseAuthTestIT.java#),You can compare if there is a mistake

Comment: here is code examples https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue , i updated from the version to 6.x , compilation error gone.

**compile group: 'com.google.firebase', name: 'firebase-admin', version: '6.11.0'**